# Variavel de Sessão não funciona WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, session

Não consigo recuperar a variável de sessão utilizando o código a seguir

Este é um arquivo para onde são enviadas requisições, la eu declaro uma variável de sessão pra utilizar em outra página que é chamada após a conclusão do arquivo.

```
<?php
    $parse_uri = explode( 'wp-content', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] );
    require_once( $parse_uri[0] . 'wp-load.php' );
    $_SESSION["enviou"] = "true";
?>
```

Nesta outra página, eu tento recuperar da forma mais simples possível

```
if ($_SESSION["enviou"] == "" || $_SESSION["enviou"] == null){
     header("location:http://www.google.com.br");   
}else{
    $_SESSION["enviou"] == null;
}
```

Mas a variável sempre esta vindo vazia, mesmo fazendo a declaração da mesma no arquivo anterior.

Ao inserir o código `session_start();` recebo os seguintes erros:

```
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: open(/var/lib/php-cgi/session/sess_6aqo4l2r50v2hguu8pnrqusvr7, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in /home/storage/a/6a/25/..../public_html/vl/wp-content/themes/....../page-formbarraresposta.php on line 2
Warning: Unknown: open(/var/lib/php-cgi/session/sess_6aqo4l2r50v2hguu8pnrqusvr7, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in Unknown on line 0`
Warning: Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/var/lib/php-cgi/session) in Unknown on line 0
```

Isso pode ser um error do servidor? Visto que esse mesmo código já foi utilizado em outro projeto e funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: Para iniciarmos uma session, usamos a função session_start(). Para um bom funcionamento, ela não pode estar depois de nenhum OUTPUT de dados (echo, print, códigos HTML, etc.). É recomendável que esteja na primeira linha do código.

Answer (score 1):

O erro é bem explicito no que diz, o caminho em que o PHP salva as sessões não existia no meu servidor, então achei o código

```
session_save_path(realpath(dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) . '/../tmp'));
session_start();
```

E aí funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: Obrigado, bela solução... tive que usar isso em uma versão muito antiga de PHP.